# Как перезаписать путь в ini-file, при создании инстолятора в Inno Setup?

Tags: файлы, windowsinstaller, inno-setup, ini

Есть `Ini file`, в нем прописан путь к директории в которой будут сохраняться данные, полученные от сервера.

Когда происходит установка этого файла, пользователь выбирает директорию, куда он хочет установить его.

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении директории, изменялась или записывалась директория в `Ini` файл и создавалась дополнительная директория, для данных?

Пример:

Есть строка в файле, `capturedFacesDestPath = "d:/temp/CapturedFaces"`,
когда юзер меняет директорию при установке, это строчка будет перезаписывается и создаваться пустая директория `"СapturedFaces"`, в директории где будет установлена программа?

Comment: Как у вас происходит выбор директории в инсталяторе?

Comment: я пробую сделать просто пример и использую директорию DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запись выбранного пути можно сделать вот так:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\INIFile.ini"; Section: "SectionName"; Key: "capturedFacesDestPath"; String: "{MyDirName}"
```

Comment: получилось, спасибо